# Restkit 0.20 NSDictionary returned instead of mapped objects

Tags: objective-c, restkit

i'm using restkit 0.20 and the objects who are returned from the GET are not of the type Category but NSDictionary?

this is my model

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Category : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* identifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* description;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* name;

@end
```

the json

```
 

    [
      {
        "category": {
          "_id": "50fc579d81d79d4db0000001",
          "name": "Category 0"
        }
      },
      {
        "category": {
          "_id": "50fc579d81d79d4db0000006",
          "name": "Category 0"
        }
      } 
    ]
```

mappings

```
RKObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[categoryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"category._id": @"identifier", @"category.name": @"name"}];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor: [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:categoryMapping objectClass:[Category class] rootKeyPath:nil]];
RKResponseDescriptor *categoryResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:categoryMapping pathPattern:@"/categories" keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:categoryResponseDescriptor];
```

if i call [RKObjectManager.sharedManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/categories", i get an array returned :) but the objects are not of the type Category, but NSDictionary.

```
    NSLog(@"%@",[cat class]);
    2013-01-26 12:01:17.247 app[18943:c07] __NSDictionaryM
```

if i call dat.name, the app will crash

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the objects returned are always dictionaries, you should map them to a class:

```
Category* c= [Category new];
c.identifier= dict[@"_id"];
c.name= dict[@"name"];
```

Every dictionary is taken from the array you got.

Comment: but in the previous version of RestKit i always got an NSArray of Category objects returned, the documentation says also ..

Answer (score 0):

whoops

```
    RKObjectMapping* catMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
```

i'm using now

```
    RKObjectMapping* catMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class]];
```

i'm rolling again :)